# Ocassional "Invalid argument" with sched_setaffinity on the Android device

Tags: android, c, operating-system, arm, affinity

I want to set CPU affinity on an Android device, but when I attempt to run code on the middle or big cores, `sched_setaffinity` occasionally returns -1. How can I resolve this issue?

My Android device features a Snapdragon 888 CPU with 8 cores: 4 Cortex-A55s (1.8GHz, IDs: 0-3), 3 Cortex-A78s (2.42GHz, IDs: 4-6), and 1 Cortex-X1 (2.84GHz, ID: 7). The operating system is Android 11.

I want to set CPU affinity in my code. This is my function which sets the affinity:

```cpp
inline int set_cpu(int core_id){
    cpu_set_t mask;
    CPU_ZERO(&mask);
    CPU_SET(core_id,&mask);
    int stat = sched_setaffinity(0,sizeof(cpu_set_t),&mask);
    if (stat != 0){
        std::cout << "Set CPU Affinity Failed! Errno " << errno << ": " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    return stat;
}
```

And I call the function `set_cpu` like this:

```cpp
void Myfunc(int core_id) {
    set_cpu(core_id);
    /* My code */
}
```

When I set `core_id` to values in {0,1,2,3}, it works fine. However, if I use `core_id` values from {4,5,6,7}, `sched_setaffinity` sometimes returns -1 with an "Invalid argument" error (Errno 22). In other words, the function is inconsistent with these values. (It seems that core 7 more often failed)

I'm unsure why this happens. How can I ensure the function works successfully every time?

Comment: Do those higher-power CPUs get shut down at times to save power?

Comment: I attempted to switch the battery saver from Balanced to Performance, but it was useless.